Issue with QUERY command due to married and maiden names
I am trying to create a tab that shows delinquent members based on another tab.
My sample data is located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hyBfQBYF1TNmVgXammI5vADWFCD2d1eA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105919111240161574477&rtpof=true&sd=true
If you look at the 2023 Delinquent Members tab, you'll notice that there are 2 entries: Betty Rubble and Wilma Flintstone.  But if you look at the 2023-TreasurerWorksheet, notice that Wilma actually paid under 2 different names, one being her married name and one being her maiden name.  So, she's actually overpaid.  She was only supposed to pay $100 and she's paid $125.  How do I get the report to not show Wilma as delinquent and still keep the others (Betty in this case) as delinquent ?
I was going to do some calculations using the ABS() to get the absolute value and add that for column F of the TreasurerWorksheet, but it looks like you can't use ABS in a QUERY.
Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

I believe the cleanest way to do it is to use the true name (called active name) in the "Donations Transactions 2023". I added it in column F of your google sheet. Then make all your analysis based upon that column. The sum will be made using the unique name. That will be more readable and avoid confusion.
